# Python-like string multiplication in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring

As a longtime Python programmer, I really appreciate Python's string multiplication feature, like this:

```
> print("=" * 5)  # =====
```

Because there is no `*` overload for C++ `std::string`s, I devised the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


std::string operator*(std::string& s, std::string::size_type n)
{
  std::string result;

  result.resize(s.size() * n);

  for (std::string::size_type idx = 0; idx != n; ++idx) {
    result += s;
  }
  return result;
}


int main()
{
  std::string x {"X"};

  std::cout << x * 5; // XXXXX
}
```

---

My question: Could this be done more idiomatic/effective (Or is my code even flawed)?

Comment: This seems to belong on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: One obvious issue is that the parameter should be `std::string const & s` instead of `std::string & s`.

Comment: The other one is that ADL will not find your operator, but there is nothing you can do about that without invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: And another thing is that it can be heavily optimized: iterating and adding `s` in each iteration is too naive!

Comment: For the specific example of a single repeated character you can construct the string directly with `std::string(5, 'X');`.

Comment: One flaw is that `resize` will create a string of null characters and the `+=` will add additional characters, not replace the nulls. Perhaps you meant `reserve` (which is kind of a premature optimization)?

Comment: @Nawaz I'm aware that `str1 += str2` is also naive in Python, too. I know how to avoid such constructs in Python as opposed to C++ --  that's the Raison d’Être for my question...

Comment: @Rakete1111 Could you elaborate on what is invoking UB?

Comment: @Christoph2 The only solution that I know of is to define the operator in `std`, but you're not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about simply using the [right constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) for your simple example:

```
std::cout << std::string(5, '=') << std::endl; // Edit!
```

For really *multiplying* **strings** you should use a simple inline function (and **`reserve()`** to avoid multiple re-allocations)

```
std::string operator*(const std::string& s, size_t n) {
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(s.size()*n);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        result += s;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and use it

```
std::cout << (std::string("=+") * 5) << std::endl;
```

See a [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/872b440485182f1b)

Comment: Fantastic answer! thanks a lot!